# unit tests for new programming features in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, nio

I'm interested to look at JUnit tests for new features in Java. Lets say I am talking about `new file system API (NIO 2.0)` which has been added into java 7. However, when I look at [OpenJDK source code](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) (or its [mirror version on Github](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/tree/master/test/java/nio)) I could not find any JUnit test. In fact, there are some code in `\openjdk\jdk\test\java\nio` which are not junit. Does anyone know whether java has been JUnit tested?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know whether java has been JUnit tested?

Evidently not, from your posted source. But from your question title:

> unit tests for new programming features in Java

Those certainly exist. In fact, [here's the one for FileAttributes](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/test/java/nio/file/Files/FileAttributes.java). This probably matches your description of "code ... which [is] not JUnit". That test, however, does automatically instantiate and call the different attribute classes, exiting normally if the tests pass and exiting with an exception if any assumptions fail.

JUnit is a fantastic library for writing and running tests, but not every unit test is a JUnit test, and you could argue that not every test written in JUnit is a "unit test" either—it may actually be an *integration* or *system* test, which would have a larger scope. The defining characteristics of "unit testing" are that the tests are small, repeatable blocks of code that exercise the smallest available module under test and confirm the results automatically, and `nio` tests do exactly that.

(*How would the tests be different if they were written in JUnit?* JUnit contains built in `assertEquals` and `assertTrue` methods, among others, and has a fancier runner that reports errors independently without the need for an explicit `main` method. On the other hand, using JUnit would also have required attaching the JUnit library, which might not have been an option for non-technical reasons. Besides, requiring a library to test the base JDK might effectively make that library a part of the JDK itself!)